# Iteration of instances inside controller and pass to context

Tags: python, django

I have started creating a personal expenses django app to learn python...
So far, I have written some models for categories, transactions, scheduled transactions (for example re-occuring bills), type of accounts etc. And I am stuck :)
What I am trying to do is to display all transactions in an html page. Those that re-occur, should be listed also, as my app displays all transactions you have until 365 days from now. I can't manage to display all instances of repeating transactions.

model

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    kind = models.ForeignKey(Kind)
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account) 
    userA = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='userA')
    userA_contribution = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
    userB = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='userB', blank=True, null=True)
    userB_contribution = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    transaction_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    transaction_date = models.DateTimeField('transaction date')
    transaction_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.transaction_text 
    # calculate days since transaction has been made    
    def days_ago(self):
        days_ago = timezone.now() - self.transaction_date 
        return days_ago.days

class ScheduledTransaction(Transaction):
    REPEATING_CHOICES = (
        ('0', 'Once'),
        ('1', 'Daily'),
        ('2', 'Every other day',),
        ('7', 'Every week'),
        ('14', 'Every two weeks'),
        ('30', 'Monthly'),
        ('90', 'Quarterly'),
        ('180', 'Six months'),
        ('365', 'Annually'),
    )
    repeated = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=REPEATING_CHOICES)
    def days_to_payment(self):
        days_to_payment = self.transaction_date - timezone.now()
        return days_to_payment.days
    def cost_per_month(self):
        cost_per_month = self.userA_contribution / int(self.repeated) * 30
        return cost_per_month
```

controller

```
def index(request):
latest_transactions_list = Transaction.objects.all().order_by('-transaction_date')[:20]
scheduled_transactions   = ScheduledTransaction.objects.all()
# create a list to save scheduleTransaction.object instances
s_instances = []
for sche in scheduled_transactions:
    s_instances.append(sche) 
    next_payment_days = int(sche.repeated) # next payment day is the repeated value, e.g. = 30 days
    base_trans_date = sche.transaction_date
    while next_payment_days < 365: 
        sche.transaction_date = base_trans_date + datetime.timedelta(days=next_payment_days)
        s_instances.append(sche)
        next_payment_days = next_payment_days + int(sche.repeated) 
accounts_dash            = Account.objects.all().order_by('-name')
date_today               = datetime.datetime.now()
context = { 'latest_transactions_list': latest_transactions_list,
            'scheduled_transactions'  : s_instances,
            'accounts_dash'           : accounts_dash, 
            'date_today'              : date_today,
}
return render(request, 'transactions/index.html', context)
```

view

```
{% for strans in scheduled_transactions %}
    {% if strans.repeated|add:0 <= 365 %}
        <tr>
            <td class="">{{ strans.transaction_date }}</td>
            <td class="text-center"><span class="label label-default">{{ strans.kind }}</span></td>
            <td class="text-center"><span class="label label-info">{{ strans.category }}</span></td>
            <td class="text-center"><a href="{{ strans.id }}/">{{ strans.transaction_text }}</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">{{ strans.userA_contribution|floatformat:2 }}€</td>
            <td class="text-center"><a href="{{ trans.repeated }}">{{ strans.repeated }}</a></td>
            <td class="text-center">{{ strans.days_to_payment }}</td>
            <td class="text-right">{{ strans.cost_per_month|floatformat:2 }}€</td>
        </tr>   
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The transaction is printed in the terminal webserver shell, but not displayed even once on the html.
Any help would be appreciated !

EDIT: Updated the controller. Now the iteration works, but I always get the latest date and the total of days_to_payment in all instances. Any ideas ?

Comment: Try to look at recurring payments from the same point of view that stores look at those things. They do save recurring orders for future re-use, but the price of those things my still change. So perhaps you could do the same thing - keep the orders and payments separate. The recurring payment is much like an order, but since the  price may vary, it could/should be saved into separate payment object rather than trying to display same object multiple times over a period.

Comment: Nice point, I haven't thought of it. As I said this is for personal use so the rent, the car insurance payment etc. will go there and I want to predict my wallet in the next 12 months. The price as you very well said might change though.. But the name or the date of the object is pretty much standardised - only the price may change so the problem exists: If there is a monthly payment e.g. Home Rent it should occur 12 times a year and I want to be able to show this on an html table.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, it's a view, not a controller.

Secondly, what you're doing with `s_instances` doesn't seem to make sense. First you declare it as `global` for no reason - it's local to the view function, so there's no need to make it global. Then you iterate through the transactions and for each one you **redefine** `s_instances` to be the value of the latest one. You should be appending to a list, not redefining it each time. And then you append two *methods*: `days_to_payment` and `cost_per_month` - without ever actually calling them. And finally, having converted your instances to a list of simple values, you attempt to call them from the template by their original property names, which they no longer have.

However, I must question why you think you need to do that at all. All the things you put into that list are simple model attributes or methods. Why not simply pass the transaction objects straight to the template? Then your template would actually work.

Comment: In the django documentation says that the views.py works as a controller in the mvc, although it's called "views". What I want to do is to go through every scheduled transaction=> check the repeating period it occurs (for example 30 days)=> Add this to the days_to_payment to find next payment date=> check again If it is <365 days and then display it. I guess that I could display all instances of a repeating payment in a year from NOW. You are right, global has no meaning and I removed it. I am trying to load them all on a list and then pass them as context to the template.

Comment: " you attempt to call them from the template by their original property names, which they no longer have. " - I just understood that :) so I'll have to call them by [x] because they are no longer are in an object...

Comment: I deleted the whole s_instances declaration inside the for loop and added s_instances.append(sche) which seems to work and scheduled transactions are displayed in the template's table. But it doesn't solve the issue of displaying the re-occuring payments.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove this useless and insane for loop from your view and you should be better:

```
def index(request):
    latest_transactions_list = Transaction.objects.order_by('-transaction_date')[:20]
    scheduled_transactions = ScheduledTransaction.objects.all()
    accounts_dash = Account.objects.order_by('-name')
    date_today = datetime.now()
    context = {'latest_transactions_list': latest_transactions_list,
               'scheduled_transactions': scheduled_transactions,
               'accounts_dash': accounts_dash, 
               'date_today': date_today,
               }
    return render(request, 'transactions/index.html', context)
```

Comment: As I said "Those that re-occur, should be listed also". The way you suggested is how all repeating transactions are displayed but only once, you don't get the 11 following months' payments added to the scheduled transactions. This was the primary version of the function.

Comment: @RobDel: Your original snippet didn't repeat anything neither, and manually building a list like you do in your edited snippet will not make any difference with the code I posted (apart from being slower and more memory hungry). Also your question was about `ScheduledTransaction` not showing up, not about them not repeating.

Comment: Forgive me about the last one, my main question is how to display the repeating ones. Referring to my little python experience, I don't see any other way than loading the instances of scheduled transactions in a list, check which can be repeated more than once in a year and append it to the list.

Comment: Why don't you write a method in your model class returning repetitions (or an empty list if it's not a repeating transaction) ? Also and FWIW, subclassing `Transaction` is possibly not a a good idea neither - a non-repeating transaction is just a repeating transaction that repeats zero times ;)

Comment: Actually Transaction does not repeat itself, so the repeating ability is only a feature of the inherited scheduledTransaction class. scheduledTransaction is a repeating Transaction. I assume tha t it isn't a good practice to load models with calculations that controllers should do. I could be wrong, but that's all I know for now :)

Comment: @RobDel: actually it's not good practice to put model logic in the views, and repetition logic of a repeating event (transaction or whatever) really belongs to the model. Neither the view nor template should have to care about this, and only the model's code should have to change if anything change in your logic. Also, the "model" part is not restricted to Django's `models.Model` classes - it can include any plain Python classes and functions you need.

Comment: even If I move the logic of my event in the model, how would it return 12 instances of an object as it returns by default one per call ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43235/discussion-between-bruno-desthuilliers-and-robdel)